# concept of density in gravitational lensing

Tags: general-relativity, relativity, density, gravitational-lensing

I may just be being very dense (no pun intended) but i'm reading up on gravitational lensing and it seems to require a notion of density (e.g. see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lensing_formalism))

I'm working on a question involving light bending around a point mass, and yet it still asks about the mean surface density of the lens (which produces an Einstein ring as an image). It being a point mass, i.e. delta function, i would surely expect an average density of 0, so I must have misunderstood the exact definition of density in this case.

Could someone please lay out exactly what surface density relates to in gravitational lensing?

Comment: A delta function has an "average" density of infinity, or $M/V$ over any finite region.  I am wondering how you're working in GR using an arbitrary mass distribution, however.

Comment: I think you may have solved it, i.e. that the mean surface density should be the mass of the object divided by the area encompassed by the Einstein ring